# C# - getting multiple data on combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox

I have a table called AirportList with airportCode, airportName, and airportCountry as the columns.
On windows application form I have one combobox that I linked to AirportList using LinQ.

I just want the combobox display, the airportName, airportCountry
here is the code:

```
cmbLocation.DataSource = (from A in cfse.AirportList
                       orderby A.airportName
                       select new
                       {
                          A.airportName, 
                          A.airportCountry
                       }).ToList();
```

With that code, the combobox display 
ex: {airportName = Los Angeles International Airport, airportCountry = United States }
and { } sign appear every line.

I want to be just Los Angeles International Airport, United States.
What wrong with my code, help me please

Comment: Query looks ok... are you sure the combobox columns are configured correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Winforms ComboBox displays its items using the result of the ToString method. In your code you create anonymous objects and the ToString applied to these instances produces your result.

You can simply declare a class used just for your combobox

```
public class AirportItem
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Country {get;set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", this.Name, this.Country);
    }
}
```

And change your code to

```
cmbLocation.DataSource = (from A in cfse.AirportList
                          orderby A.airportName
                          select new AirportItem
                          {
                              Name = A.airportName,
                              Country = A.airportCountry
                          }).ToList();
```

Now the select expression creates an instance of the AirportItem class and this class has an override of the ToString method that returns exactly what you want to display in the combobox.

Answer (score 2):

A combobox doesn't have columns, so you'll have to convert the object to a string. You can do this by using the `DisplayMember` property of Combobox.

First, create a wrapper class:

```
public class Airport {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Country { get; set; }

  public string DisplayName {
    get { return Name + ", " + Country; }
  }
}
```

And then put the data inside the wrapper class:

```
cmbLocation.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
cmbLocation.DataSource = 
    (from A in cfse.AirportList
     orderby A.airportName
     select new Airport { 
          Name = A.airportName, 
          Country = A.airportCountry
     }).ToList();
```